# css and underline

Tags: css

Why is the link using the underline?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#text{
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Text text text <br/>
<div id = "text">
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because this is the default (user agent css have this rule, to apply underline in every tag a). The default isn't `inherit`, so even if parent tag has underline, the child won't get it.

---

**EDIT 1:**

For example, firefox have this rule:

```
*|*:-moz-any-link {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Default would be:

```
*|*:-moz-any-link {
    text-decoration:inherit;
}
```

Then, in your example, the tag `a` would inherit `div` text-decoration.

---

**EDIT 2:**

You can overwrite default behavior with:

```
a {
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the default behavior of the `a` tag. It doesn't match the `#text` style.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to replace this...

`#text{
  text-decoration: none;
}`

with this...

`#text a:link{
  text-decoration:none;
}`

this tells the rule to apply to all anchors that are children of the tag who's id is 'text'

Answer (score 0):

It's included in the default browser CSS. It's just as if this was included prior to your style tag:

```
a{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Sure, the link also matches `#text`, but since `a` is more specific, it wins. Any attributes not explicitly specified by the browser's `a` (such as font-size) will be inherited.